# Get file name with system IO

Tags: c#, file-io

I'm working on a C# script that has to access a random file during runtime, the problem is that the files are being generated on the fly by another source and I have no means of knowing their names, I have solved a first issue which is to get how many files there are in my working directory:

```
            s = @"C:\Imagenes";
            System.IO.DirectoryInfo d = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(s);
    int files;
    files = d.GetFiles().Length;
    Debug.Log(files.ToString());
    return files;
```

Now I would like to acces a random element in my working dicrectory, but since I don't have a clue what their names are, is there a way to get their names by index or something?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4cyf24ss.aspx

Comment: -1 Sorry, but not enough information in the question. You've solved the first issue, but what's the second issue? Knowing the files names won't help, they're assigned randomly (BTW GetFiles() returns an array of the file names in the folder). Do you need the lastest created file? The latest accessed file? Would you like an event raised when a new file is created in the folder (for this use `FileSystemWatcher` class)

Comment: Marco: I don't understand how knowing the file names helps you. You can _randomly_ choose a file, but there's no guarantee that it will be the correct file. Am I right here or is my thinking just wrong headed? If I'm wrong can you tell me why? If I'm right, have a think about what you actually need, and update the question? Thanks.

Comment: Ok, I'll explain what I'm trying to accomplish, I have a system that uploads pictures from a digital camera wirelessly and automatically to a computer running my app in a given folder. What the app has to do is get a random picture and use it as an OpenGL texture, to do that I have to know the image file name, but since different camera brands and models have a different naming standard for files, I can't know beforehand what their names will be, so I thougth it'd be better tho have the code find a valid name, so I don't get crashes or whatnot. So there's actually no 'correct' file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

DirectoryInfo.GetFiles will give you array of fileInfo objects. From that you can get the file name using FileInfo.Name

Comment: If the file names as assigned randomly, how does knowing the file names help the asker?

Comment: Well i thought he jst wanted to know the filesnames which was getting created randomly.

Comment: Yes, it does help, the problem is that names don't follow a 'pattern' or anything that I can use to acces the files by name in code, but I do need to know the names.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `FileInfo` objects that are returned by `d.GetFiles()`:

```
DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo("c:\\path");

foreach (FileInfo file in d.GetFiles())
{
    string name = file.Name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
FileInfo[] fileinfos = d.GetFiles();

foreach (FileInfo FI in fileinfos)
{
string fullname = FI.FullName;
string name = FI.Name;

// do someting...
}
```

see

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4cyf24ss.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you want a random file, but this should work (except files get deleted during calculation of length and getting a rondom one)

```
int length = d.GetFiles().Length;
Random rnd = new Random();
var randomFile = d.GetFiles().ElementAt(rnd.Next(0, length-1);
```